# Detect if Minimongo denied a collection write operation

Tags: meteor, permissions, access-denied, minimongo

How can the client code of a Meteor app detect that a write operation (`insert`, `remove`, `update`) against a collection was denied, so that it can display an appropriate error message?

```
Collection.remove(id)
```

The console will display:

> remove failed: Access denied

Answer (score 0):

This is rather obvious, but Google didn't do a good job of surfacing the [relevant documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert): you need to pass a callback parameter:

```js
Collection.remove(id, function (error) {
  if (error)
    sAlert.error(error.toString());
});
```